# Dock panel settings are not visible after upgrading to 22.04.1

Tags: 22.04

After upgrading my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.1 yesterday using sudo do-release-upgrade -d, my dock panel only shows up if I move the cursor to the top left corner of the screen or if I press the [Super] key.

I tried to check on Settings >> Appearance, but the only thing there is the Style settings.

[image: Appearance settings]

Is this an expected behavior on 22.04.1?

Another different behavior I'm experiencing is that the Shift + PrtScrn to select the screenshot area stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I found another user's previous question, it may be helpful, but I do not guarantee that it will work: askubuntu.com/questions/1403431/update-to-22-04-problem-with-dock